# "throwing" token in function name changes function behaviour

Tags: spring, exception, kotlin

I'm creating a Spring boot application using Kotlin. This is part of a class I use for integration testing a Spring repository:

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension::class)
@SpringBootTest
@TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
class ImageRepositoryTest {
    @Autowired
    lateinit var imageRepository: ImageRepository

    private val image: Image

    init {
        image = Image(1, "image.jpg", "/image.jpg", "http://test/image.jpg")
    }


    @Test
    fun `refuses to store duplicated images throwing a DataIntegrityViolationException` () {
        imageRepository.save(image)
        assertThrows<DataIntegrityViolationException> {imageRepository.save(image)}
    }
}
```

This is the definition of the Image class:

```
import javax.persistence.*

@Entity
@Table(name = "image")
data class Image(@Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO) var id: Int,
                 @Column(unique = true, nullable = false) val name: String,
                 @Column (unique = true, nullable= false) val path: String,
                 @Column (unique = true, nullable= false) val url: String)
```

When executed, the test fails saying that no exception has been thrown (while it should). However, if the name of the function doesn't contain the token "throwing", (for instance, I renamed it `refuses to store duplicated images raising a DataIntegrityViolationException` the test is successful.
It seems like the presence of that token in the name of the function prevents it from throwing exceptions. Is this an intended behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to reproduce your issue with the following code, but everything works as expected:

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test
import org.junit.jupiter.api.assertThrows

class ThrowsTest {

    private val repository = ImageRepository()

    @Test
    fun `refuses to store duplicated images throwing a IllegalArgumentException`() {
        assertThrows<IllegalArgumentException> {
            repository.save()
        }
    }
}

class ImageRepository {

    fun save() {
        throw IllegalArgumentException("Already saved")
    }
}
```

How are you executing your test? IntelliJ, Maven, Gradle? Can you slim down your example, for example by removing the Spring dependency?